# I want to transfer data from one html page to other through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created two frameset , one is fixed and other is changing . The data is created through JavaScript (dynamically) and that data I have to send virtually to other html page . basically in this Project I am Using only html , CSS , JavaScript.

---> I created random list of student Using JavaScript in one html page and that generated student list I wish to send in another html page which is named as notice page by using JavaScript.

How I can do it? I tried local storage option but it not worked.

Comment: What problem you encountered with local storage approach ? Sounds plausible.

Comment: Html pages are in different computers?. Maybe you need websockets but a simple script running on a server have to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `sessionStorage`. You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)